# Fact and agenda windows are missing in CLIPS IDE?

Tags: clips

Don`t see how to call fact and agenda windows in CLIPS IDE. So, i installed CLIPS IDE latest version, i see next image when i open it: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHa04.png. In all tutorials i see, in all videos, there is window section but i don`t see any. Also, there are no options when i click file except "quit" lol. Does anyone else face similar issue and if so, how did you solve it?
I used this file to install CLIPS IDE https://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/files/CLIPS/6.40/clips_windows_64_bit_installer_640.msi/download

I tries to reinstall it, i tried to play a little bit with settings but there is not much i can do, i even can`t change font for some reason(I mean, i can, but when i press "OK" it just returns to default values).

Answer (score 1):

You can open the fact and agenda windows from the Debug menu. The Windows IDE doesn't have an integrated editor so there are no commands under the File menu for working with text files as there are for the macOS and Java Swing IDEs. Commands for loading CLIPS source files are in the Environment menu. If you try changing the browser font but don't have one of the browser windows open, you wouldn't see any changes. I don't recall any other reports of issues with changing the font in the dialog windows, but the font doesn't change until after you've pressed the OK button.

Comment: When setting the Dialog Font or Browser Font, please make sure to select one of the available fonts. In my case, the Dialog Font wasn't automatically set to a default font, and the changes related to Font Size were not applied.